# Error in android tetris - getEntry

Tags: android, surfaceview, tetris, surfaceholder

At the time me and a friend are programming the classic game Tetris, for a school project. I have been programming for an while now and had implemented both a rotate and a moveBlock, and newBlock, draw, etc., methods, so I thought now maybe would be the perfect time to run it for the first time. But then i get the error msg:

```
11-11 21:27:41.877: WARN/ResourceType(473): getEntry failing because entryIndex 7 is beyond type entryCount 7
11-11 21:27:41.877: WARN/ResourceType(473): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060007 (t=5 e=7) in package 0: 0x80000001
11-11 21:27:51.697: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-11 21:27:51.697: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45009538 com.prosjekt.tetris2/.TetrisandroidGameActivity}
```

I'm running it with a Thread that uses a self built View (surfaceHolder/surfaceView), with methods, basically I'm following an lesson that the teacher has, where she programmed a snake game. So with updating of the methods so they are correct with tetris it should work, but now I can't see the error. Anyone know what the error message means, just paste questions if more info needed.

I have added a lot of LOG commands and I just got LOG from the TetrisView (surfaceView) constructor and from the constructor in the Thread, so it's never inside any of the methods.